# css target chrome on windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, css

Is there anyway to target chrome on windows? I'm looking to do this because of the difference in border-radius rendering. Chrome on osx seems to work fine, only problematic in Chrome on Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, really have to do this, I recommend this CSS Browser Selector script:

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Of course, you'll have to update your site when the browser issue gets fixed. :p